# Unable to execute PHPUnit Tests in Adobe Commerce (Magento 2)

Tags: doctrine, phpunit, phpstorm, magento2, allure

I’m running a local Docker instance of Adobe Commerce (Magento 2) with the following versions:

```
Magento Enterprise version 2.4.3-p3 
phpunit/phpunit version 9.5.28
doctrine/annotations version 2.0.0
allure-framework/allure-php-api version 1.4.0
```

I’m unable to run PHPUnit tests in PhpStorm (Build #PS-223.8214.64)

The error I’m getting is the following:

> Call to undefined method Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerUniqueLoader()

Searching for `registerUniqueLoader` in the vendor directory, I’m seeing the following in `Yandex\Allure\Adapter\Annotation\AnnotationProvider:: registerAnnotationNamespaces()`

```php
public static function registerAnnotationNamespaces()
{
    AnnotationRegistry::registerUniqueLoader('class_exists');
}
```

However, class `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry` only has methods `reset()` and `loadAnnotationClass()`.

Is there a set of module versions I need to be at in order to be able to run PHPUnit tests? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `doctrine/annotations version to 1.14.2` in `composer.json`. It works for me.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much for your help. In terms of the DocBlock annotations, I'm unable to use the Configuration Fixture detailed at this link: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/testing/guide/integration/annotations/magento-config-fixture/


I'm getting the following error: 
Class Magento\TestFramework\Annotation\ConfigFixture does not exist

Do you know how to resolve this issue?